# Get practial resistances for the Current Divider

Tags: resistance, current-limiting, practical

[image]

**My understanding**

1. The resistance as seen through the load is just Rs, Therefore `60K <
   Rs < 80K`.
2. Is (current Through Rs Resistance)
   IL (current through RL load)
   `Is/IL = RL/Rs`, because of the limit IL ~ 40uA we get Is as 60uA and RL = (3*Rs/2)

when I choose **Rs = 56K and RL =  82K** I am getting wrong answer. I understood that I am going wrong somewhere. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: I've read this twice now and I'm struggling to understand what you are trying to do or what your question is.

Comment: Clue: the total resistance of any two resistors in parallel is *always* less than the smallest value part. As 56k is below 60k, you will always have < 56k (just what value is left as an exercise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's the same voltage across both resistors, then if there's \$ 40\mu A\$ through Rl and \$ 60\mu A\$ through Rs, Rl must be equal to 1.5 times Rs.

Your job, then, is to pick from the list, two resistors with a resistance ratio of 1.5 which when paralleled present an equivalent resistance of 60k\$\Omega\$. Or 80k\$\Omega\$. Or anything in between...

Looking for a 60k\$\Omega\$ solution,

If we set \$ Rs = 1 \text { and } R_l = 1.5\$, we can write:

$$k= \frac{R_s\times R_l}{R_s+R_l}= \frac{1.5}{2.5}=0.6 $$

and then:  $$Rs =\frac{Rt}{k} = \frac{60k\Omega}{0.6} = 100k\Omega $$

and, since the resistance of Rl is 1.5 times that of Rs:

$$ R_L = 1.5 \times R_s = 150k\Omega$$

Consulting the list, we find 10 and 15, so we lucked out with a perfect match!

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the accept. I hope I helped you to learn something instead of just helping you to beat a test.  Kudos are due, however, to whoever thought up the puzzle and hid the perfect solution in plain sight.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be doing an unnecessarily convoluted approach.

Given that the total source current \$I_s = 100\mu A\$ and the terminal resistance \$60k\Omega \le R_T \le 80k\Omega\$, then the terminal voltage is \$ 6V \le V_T \le 8V\$.

This yields, for a desired current through \$R_L\$ of \$40\mu A\$ a nominal resistance of \$175k\Omega\$ and a nominal resistance for \$R_S\$ of \$116.667k\Omega\$ using the nominal voltage of 7V (the centre value of the range).

These values do indeed evaluate to \$70k\Omega\$

Finding standard E12 series parts and evaluating tolerance performance is left to you.